# Connection and Collection Interfaces in Java

Tags: java, collections, interface, connection

Which class implements all the `Connection` Interfaces which are in `javax.microedition.io` package and how?

And in the same way which class implements the some of `Collection` interfaces like `Iterator` interface. 
I saw a code: -

```
Iterator it;
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

it = list.iterator();
```

The `iterator()` return type is "`Iterator`" which is an interface.

Please tell me what this code is doing is it returning an object of type `Iterator`? but as far as I know, interface can't be initialized.

Comment: Which Connection interface? Please specify the package name.

Comment: Could you please provide the full qualified class name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it = list.iterator();

here the iterator() method is returning an object which implements the iterator interface. This is built in feature provided by java.

In J2ME the Connection interfaces, like Bozho said, `javax.microedition.io`.Connector is a factory class for all kind of connections. And the implementations of those interfaces are again built in feature.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean java.sql.Connection? If so ...

The Connection interface is implemented by the JDBC driver provider (Oracle etc.) and the implementation of that interface is instantiated and returned via the java.sql.DriverManager The implementation of this interface would be found in the jar file you are including in your class path for your project.

Comment: the question is about j2me, so java.sql.Connection isn't the first guess.

Comment: it is now ... when it was first posted it was a completely different question ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're questioned about connection interfaces that were defined in javax.microedition.io package. (Ignore if this is not the case)

MIDP provides few connection interfaces as like CommConnection, HttpConnection, SocketConnection and etc.

You can get it's instance reference by using Connector. For example,

```
HttpConnection c = (HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://www.google.com");
```

We called it GCF(Generic Connection Framework). Please find more information about GCF from http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/genericframework/

Comment: Hey Thanks Wonil Kim
I'm talking about javax.microedition.io package.
I see the following code somewhere but I can't find the implementation of "getLength()" method which is defined in ContentConnection interface..

the code is following 
            hc = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
            int length = (int)hc.getLength();

My program is running nicely and giving me the byte length of the image file which I'm using with "url" parameter. 
But I'm unable to understand from where the length is coming.
The getLength() method is not defined in any class.

Comment: Hello Bhupi, you don't need to worry about internal implementation. You just can use interface functionality without knowledge of internal implementation.
But, if you still want to see what's going on, I recommend to see phoneME open source for JavaME implementation.
From it, you can find real implementation of these interfaces. For example, please see Protocol.java file under midp\src\protocol\http\reference\classes\com\sun\midp\io\j2me\http.
This is reference implementation of HttpConnection interface.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [javax.microedition.io.Connector](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr218/javax/microedition/io/Connector.html) as a factory for Connections. The implementations it provides are not your concern.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the library you are using, for example if you are using JDBC. You will find `JdbcOdbcConnection` which implements `JdbcOdbcConnectionInterface` which extends `Connection`

You get the connection object through the DriverManager.getConnection which takes a Driver library.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about java.sql.Connection. JDBC is a specification which defines a Java Interface (several actually). Connection is one of them.

The implementations of Connection are to be found in the various JDBC drivers, provided by  he DBMS vendors and independent driver makers.

Answer (score 0):

the java sources can be obtained, so you can have a look yourself at what `iterator()` is doing.

To help you on your way, here's a link to the [AbstractList](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/AbstractList-source.html) source as implemented by the GNU Classpath team. Classpath is an alternative (open-source) implementation of parts of Java. It may not be exactly how Sun (now Oracle) does it, but it will give you some insight.

I chose `AbstractList` because that's where the `ArrayList.iterator()` is implemented.

As you can see, it returns an anonymous (inner) class implementing `Iterator`.